# Adding Dojo 1.6+ in Lotus Notes database v8.5.3

Tags: dojo, lotus-notes, xpages

Lotus Notes 8.5.3 uses dojo 1.5.1. However I want to use dojo 1.6/1.7 library in my NSF database. How can I do it? I tried to use the technique suggested by [Keith Strickland in his blog](http://xprentice.gbs.com/A55BAC/keithstric.nsf/default.xsp?documentId=C38339FBE7158BFE852579420054EC4C) but no luck.

I need to include the dojo library in NSF database and not on server.

The reason I want to do this so as to use the advanced Dojo Mobile libraries (from dojo 1.6/1.7) in my XPages.

**UPDATE:** I even [posted this question on XPages forum](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/xpagesforum.nsf/topicThread.xsp?documentId=411E4ECD7E4270CF8525794B004DA4A1&action=openDocument) some time back but no replies.

Comment: Per is correct. See [Paul's blog](http://www.intec.co.uk/domino-8-5-3-greater-power-over-dojo-thanks-ibm-for-your-work/) for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Domino 8.5.3 server uses Dojo 1.6.1 for XPages. You should see this if you view the HTML source of a test application.

As an example, I see this in one of my applications:
"/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.6.1/dojo/dojo.js"

If you are going to create apps using Dojo Mobile then take a look at the Extension Library and the latest Upgrade Pack 1 for Domino 8.5.3. Both includes XPages Mobile controls.

Comment: @Naveen please mark your question as answered (if you agree with Niklas Heidloff that my answer is correct). Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Per's correct that the Dojo plugin that is loaded by default is 1.6.1 (the ".1" is because it includes IBM-specific code and this means it differentiates it from anything a developer has added in).

The files in the js folder on the server / client are 1.5.1 and this is needed for iNotes.

You can change the Dojo version in the xsp.properties by setting xsp.client.script.dojo.version in Package Explorer. Incidentally UP1 offers a nice visual editor for the xsp.properties file.

However, currently if you change this setting you need to uncheck "Use runtime optimized javaScript and CSS resources" or it will still use the plugin. I noticed this too late for anything to be done before the Gold release.

If you add 1.7 files to the server and include the IBM folder from 1.5.1 it may work. AFAIK there's no way to get the IBM folder from the plugin code.

See my blog post for more details: http://www.intec.co.uk/domino-8-5-3-greater-power-over-dojo-thanks-ibm-for-your-work/